# My website uses Facebook Connect as a login option, should I have an application AND a “page” in the Facebook ecosystem?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

So I am working on revamping one of my older websites that is actually based around a local area with a strong community. Adding facebook as a login option was a no brainer but now I'm faced with a question I don't know the answer to. I obviously needed to create a facebook application to handle the login/logout but now I am not sure if I should also create a facebook page as well. It seems you can currently "Like" an application but I want to also be able to send out messages to people who have "Liked" my application and post events. Not sure if this is possible with just an application but am worried it may cause some confusion if I have an application and a facebook page with the same name.

What is everyone else doing?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Facebook page for your application.  And you can have a Facebook page with the same name as your application because your application runs from `apps.facebook.com` and your page will run on `www.facebook.com`.

Comment: Additionally, if you register a vanity URL for your app's page, the app page will be treated like any normal Facebook page and be accessible from `www.facebook.com`.